# Combining tbl_strata summary tables in R

Tags: r, tbl

I want to combine three table strata table summary objects. You can't merge them with the tbl_merge function. What can I do?

I have three tables like this:

```
table_one <- data %>%
  select(Var1m, Var2, Var3, Var4, Var5, Var6, Var7) %>% 
  tbl_strata(
    strata = Var7,
    .tbl_fun =
      ~ .x %>%
      tbl_summary(by = Var6, missing = "no") %>%
      add_p(),
    .header = "**{strata}**, N = {n}"
  )
```

The library is the gt_summary library.
The goal is to have all Characteristics for the variables once on the left and then table one with the two groups, table two with the two groups and three with the groups next to each other in one table.
Here ist a pictore of what I'm trying to achieve:

[image: see picture of summary table below (my tables will be based on three different data sets (same format but different number of cases)]

I'm not sure what I'm missing. I tried the svryr library combine() function, transforming the tables into dfs and then combining.. combining by bind_rows

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site.  It would help if you could make a small reproducible example with a clear description of the output that you are trying to achieve.  Also say which packages these functions come from.  See the responses to this question on how to make a good R question.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: Thank you! I tried to update it with a picture and the relevant library.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you are attempting to use two levels of stratification. The example you posted uses one level only, by Grade (I, II, & III).
I think `tbl_strata` only supports one level, so you'll need to structure your data accordingly.

One thing you could try is to merge the data used for `table_one` with the data used for the (I'm assuming from your example) `table_two` and `table_three`.
From your example, it looks like you're using `Var7` to stratify data, so I'll assume `table_two` and `table_three` contain `Var8` and `Var9`, respectively. Using `pivot_longer`, for example, you can merge all three of these into a single variable, which you then pass to `tbl_strata` as your stratification variable.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(gtsummary)

merged_data <- bind_rows(  # this will depend on your data so it might not be as simple as here...
 data,
 data_for_table_two,
 data_for_table_three
) %>%
pivot_longer(cols = c(Var7, Var8, Var9))

table_merged <- merged_data %>%
  select(Var1m, Var2, Var3, Var4, Var5, Var6, Var789) %>% 
  tbl_strata(
    strata = Var789,
    .tbl_fun =
      ~ .x %>%
      tbl_summary(by = Var6, missing = "no") %>%
      add_p(),
    .header = "**{strata}**, N = {n}"
  )
```